# handling dates in java of different format itself

Tags: java

I have below this method

in which inside the parameter stringValue in can receive the date in string data type as

```
06/20/13
```

or i can recieve the date as

```
16/02/2018
```

so i should be able to parse it and send it to Date type 
rite now from the below code i am able to achieve it but the issues is that my year part is deducted so upon debugging i found it is coming as

```
[Date: year: 13 month : 7 day:5 ] for date type 06/20/13
```

now i want year to come as

```
[Date: year: 2013 month : 7 day:5 ]
```

it is coming correct for 16/02/2018 this one , please advise how should i correct it for above format so that it should work for both the dates .

```
public static Date convertStringToDate(String stringValue) {
        Date iceDate = null;
        java.util.Date javaDate = new java.util.Date();
        String[] formatStrings = { "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd-MMM-yyyy" };
        // DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",
        // Locale.ENGLISH);
        for (String formatString : formatStrings) {

            try {
                javaDate = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString)
                        .parse(stringValue);
                iceDate = new Date(javaDate);
                return iceDate;
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                logger.warn("##$$$$$### Error in invoice inside convertStringToDate method : ##$$$$$$#### "
                        + ErrorUtility.getStackTraceForException(e));

            }
        }
        return null;

    }
```

The date format is in DD/MM/Yy and I am using Java 5.  Please advise

Comment: "so i should be able to parse it and send it to Date type rite" - not if you don't know the format, no. Does "05/06/2015" represent May 6th or June 5th?

Comment: @JonSkeet  it repesents  5 day anf 6 month that is june and year is 2015

Comment: How do you know it represents day 5 and month 6 rather than day 6 and month 5? Bear in mind that you claim "06/20/13" is valid input, which puts the day second. That's my point - you've got an ambiguous set of date formats, at which point it's game over.

Comment: @hfkjflhfjgdjdhkd Jon makes a good point. In the US, dates are treated as MM/dd/yy and in the UK it is treated as dd/MM/yy. The user needs to know the locale they are working in. What version of Java are you using? Java 8 has some new support for dates worth looking into, otherwise using a package outside of the java core libraries is preferable (e.g., Joda).

Comment: @Nick Allen Well this the way that is being already told so it is coming in dd//mm/yy format moreover it is UK format , i am using java 5

Comment: If it's UK format, how come you've got a value of "06/20/13"? That *isn't* in dd/mm/yy format.

Comment: Java 5!!! Find another job, turn in your resignation and get the Hell out of there. At a minimum, you'd want Java 7. You are missing out on so many opportunities to grow your skills. #sorry #offtopic

Comment: Yeah I know but please for rite now please advise how to overcome  from  this error by using Java 5

Comment: For solutions using modern Java, search for the many Questions and Answers using the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to work with dates, once you are receiving a String.

You will need only to assume a rule, if you are receiving a 2 digit year, you need to work with a range of years and choose the correct century to the input.

Example:
20/11/78 then is 20/11/1978
20/11/05 then is 20/11/2005
Once you've assumed to work in this condition, you can complement the 2 digit year with this condition:

```
        if(Integer.valueOf(year)>70) {
                year="19"+year;
            }else {
                year="20"+year;
            }
```

Look the code below:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Data {

 // four digit input
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        String dateFour = "16/02/18";
        String tokens[] = dateFour.split("/"); // dd=0 MM=1 yyyy=2 or yy=2
        String year = tokens[2];
        if (year.length() < 3) {
            if (Integer.valueOf(year) > 70) {
                year = "19" + year;
                System.out.println(year);
            } else {
                year = "20" + year;
                System.out.println(year);
            }
        }
        buffer.append("[Date: year: " + year + " month : " + Integer.valueOf(tokens[1]) + " day:" + Integer.valueOf(tokens[0]) + " ] for date type " + date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ops");
    }
    System.out.println(buffer.toString());
}



}
```

You will have this response from sysout:

> [Date: year: 18 month : 2 day:16 ] for date type 16/02/18

Comment: you can parse the String using "/" as separator, once you count four characters on left, you can use literal characters converting month and year to integer, once you are receiving a String

Answer (score -1):

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy")
```

will do the trick, and it will work for both 2 and 4 digit years

for example

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String date = "16/02/2018";
    Date d = null;
    try {
        d = sdf1.parse(date);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ops");
    }
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

will generate

```
Fri Feb 16 00:00:00 BRST 2018
```

Comment: Thanks , so can i update the same in my above piece of code also , it will be a great help if you can also please make changes in my above piece of code also , i can grasp more thanks in advance

Comment: How is that going to handle input of "06/20/13"?

Comment: @jon that the point , i am looking for solution that will handle both the case that is if date is comin in 2 digits 
( and if date is coming in 4 digits format also

Comment: @hfkjflhfjgdjdhkd: You've missed my point - the differences aren't just in terms of "2 digit year vs 4 digit year" - they're in terms of "day/month/year" vs "month/day/year".

Comment: Jon as I have told you that it is UK format so it is dd/mm/yy format